# Combining two queries into one query

Tags: sql

**Query 1**

```
select test_id, count (student_id)*100/ 
  (select count(distinct student_id)from test_taken)as "pass rate"
from test_taken
where result>50
group by test_id;
```

**Query 2**

```
 select test_id, count (student_id)*100/ 
    (select count(distinct student_id)from test_taken)as "fail rate"
 from test_taken
 where result<50
 group by test_id;
```

I have the following 
Table:

```
test_taken
Columns:test_id,student_id,result
```

I am looking to get the percentage pass rate and fail rate where a pass is result >50% and fail is result <50%.

I have the pass rate and fail rate as 2 separate queries but I want them combined into one query.

Comment: What about those who got result = 50.. you don't want to include them in any category?

Comment: AH YES. I SUPPOSE < 50 IS A FAIL (0-49) AND 50 AND ABOVE IS A PASS. THANK YOU FOR POINTING THAT OUT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the result of the two queries is equal in terms of column numbers and column types, you can use `UNION` to get one table result :

```
SELECT test_id, 
       COUNT (student_id) * 100 / (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT student_id) 
                               FROM   test_taken)AS rate 
FROM   test_taken 
WHERE  result > 50 
GROUP  BY test_id; 

UNION

SELECT test_id, 
       COUNT (student_id) * 100 / (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT student_id) 
                               FROM   test_taken)AS rate 
FROM   test_taken 
WHERE  result < 50 
GROUP  BY test_id;
```

Comment: How do I get 2 column results. a 'pass rate' column and a 'fail rate' column. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT test_id, 
       sum(case when result > 50 then 1 else 0 end) * 100 / (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT student_id) 
                                   FROM   test_taken) AS "pass rate",
       sum(case when result < 50 then 1 else 0 end) * 100 / (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT student_id) 
                                   FROM   test_taken) AS "fail rate" 
FROM   test_taken 
GROUP  BY test_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The OPs solution does not produce a correct result (at least not the one specified in the requirements) so expanding on that with UNION or other methods is NOT a valid answer. He seems to be calculating the percentages on the entire number of students instead of just the ones that took a specific test.

A query which would produce the correct result for each test is the following:

```
select Q1.test_id, 
   Q1.students_passed * 100 / Q1.total_students || '%' as pass_rate,
   Q1.students_failed * 100 / Q1.total_students || '%' as fail_rate
from       
(SELECT test_id, 
   sum(case when result > 50 then 1 else 0 end) students_passed,
   sum(case when result < 50 then 1 else 0 end) students_failed,
   count(distinct student_id) total_students
FROM   test_taken 
GROUP  BY test_id) Q1;
```

We first count how many students have passed and failed using the SUM function. We add one to the sum when our coditions are met, i.e result > 50 or result < 50, else we add zero.

We also need to count the total nr. of students that have taken a test, so we can do that easily with count(distinct student_id) and grouping by test_id.

Finally we wrap this query in the outer one, in which we divide the the nr. of students passed and failed to the total nr of students for each a given test_id.

For the input table:

```
1  | 1 | 51
1  | 2 | 30
2  | 3 | 60
2  | 4 | 22
3  | 2 | 66
```

it produces the output:

```
1  | 50%  | 50%
2  | 50%  | 50%
3  | 100% | 0%
```

Comment: THE TEST_TAKEN TABLE ONLY DISPLAYES THE STUDENTS(STUDENT_ID) WHO TOOK THE TEST.